# Trying to serialize a XML to JSon c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml

I'm new at c#, and in my job I have a aplication that returns this xml

```
 <ListaResultado PaginaAtual="1" TotalPaginas="1">
      <ItemMenu name="consultas" id="123" caminho="abc" />
     <ItemMenu name="consultas2" id="123" caminho="abc2" />
     <ItemMenu name="consultas3" id="123" caminho="abc3" />
</ListaResultado>
```

and output of no it's nod valid cause the final result it's

```
"ListaResultado":{"PaginaAtual":1,"TotalPaginas":"3", 
"ItemMenu":{"name":"consultas", "id":"123", "caminho":"abc"},
"ItemMenu":{"name":"consultas2", "id":"123", "caminho":"abc2"},
"ItemMenu":{"name":"consultas3", "id":"123", "caminho":"abc3"}}
```

i'm need the correct

```
"ItemMenu":[{"name":"consultas", "id":"123", "caminho":"abc"},{"name":"consultas2", "id":"123", "caminho":"abc2"},{"name":"consultas3", "id":"123", "caminho":"abc3"}]
```

someone have some clue? the examples that i found use que correct xml 123 that's not my case... 
thanks !!!

Comment: So parse the XML and re-serialize it as JSON. Are you having trouble with this (if so post your code and where exactly you are going wrong)?

Comment: how did you get the `json`?

Answer (score 0):

First you can use `LoadXml`, then use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for reserializing it to JSON:

```
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(@"<ListaResultado PaginaAtual='1' TotalPaginas='1'>
          <ItemMenu name='consultas' id='123' caminho='abc' />
          <ItemMenu name='consultas2' id='123' caminho='abc2' />
          <ItemMenu name='consultas3' id='123' caminho='abc3' />
     </ListaResultado>");
    var doc = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xml);
```